# Use Deflater to compressor file, The compressed file is different under Android 12 and Android 10

Tags: java, android, zip, compression

test code:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "patchTest");
        File dex = new File(dir, "classes.dex");
        File compressDex = new File(dir, "compressDex");
        Deflater compressor = new Deflater(9, true);
        compressor.setStrategy(0);
        try {
            Log.i("hc", "compress start " + Sha256Utils.getHash(dex));
            DeflaterOutputStream compressedPatchOut =
                    new DeflaterOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(compressDex), compressor, true);
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(dex);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 2];
            int index;
            while ((index = fin.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                compressedPatchOut.write(bytes, 0, index);
            }
            compressedPatchOut.finish();
            compressedPatchOut.flush();
            fin.close();
            Log.i("hc", "compress finish " + Sha256Utils.getHash(compressDex));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            compressor.end();
        }
```

Finally, the Hash value of the compressed file is different between Android 12 and Android 10.
Is there any modification to the Deflater of Android12?

Comment: Where does the `classes.dex` file come from that you hash? You are hashing the file before and after the compression. Are bith hashes different or just the one after compression? How do you install the app on both devices (is it the same APK file)?

Comment: Does the compressed data from both decompress correctly? If so, then it does not matter if the compressed data is different.

Comment: The classdex file comes from the release version of Apk. After the APK is decompressed on the PC (Windows 10), the dex file is pushed to the phone for compression testing of different Android versions. It is found that the compressed files of the Android12 version are different. This release version of Apk can be installed normally in each Android version and can be used normally @Robert

Comment: The decompressed class.dex file is the same, and it is different on Android12 and Android10 after compression. The decompression operation is performed on the pc (windows10), decompressed from the release version APK, and then push the decompressed dex file to the phone @MarkAdler

Comment: release APK link: 
https://dldir1.qq.com/weixin/android/weixin8016android2040_arm64.apk   , After decompressing the APK, push the class.dex file to the phone

Comment: I still don't see the point in this question. If the output is different so what (nobody has defined that compressing a file creates a deterministic result). Does that has any disadvantages (can not be read/decompressed by older devices or something like that). Most likely Google has simply changed the deflate implementation to use https://github.com/google/zopfli instead as it provides better compression rates but is compatible with deflate.

Comment: The same file is compressed using the same compression parameters on different Android devices, and the results obtained are not the same. This will cause the decompression to fail after uploading the file to the server in the app, and it is impossible to verify whether the file uploaded by the user is correct

Comment: We expect that the hash value of the uploaded file after compression is 1234567. This is expected to be correct on Android10 devices, but the hash value is not 1234567 on Android12 devices, so our upload verification function will fail on Android12 devices.

Comment: If I want to use the deflate api to compress files and keep the same results as other Android versions, how is it compatible?
@Robert